# Python OpenCV как получить размер найденного фрагмента?

Tags: python, opencv

```
small_image = cv2.imread('fragment.png')
large_image = cv2.imread('screen.jpg')

result = cv2.matchTemplate(small_image, large_image, method)


mn,_,mnLoc,_ = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

MPx,MPy = mnLoc
```

Я использую этот код для поиска начала X и Y координат фрагмента на картинке, как мне получить конечные координаты фрагмента? Фрагменты на картинке могут ,snm разных размеров.

Comment: Что имеется в виду - если реальный размер совпадения меньше small_image ?

Comment: Он может быть как меньше, так и больше. Код находит фрагмент при разных размерах, но как мне узнать размер найденного фрагмента по пикселям?

Comment: Если больше - значит, маленькая картинка вырезана из бОльшего образца? Не вижу простого решения - ведь даже при меньшем размере совпадение может быть неполным, и начинаться не в левом верхнем углу (mnLoc)